# SQL multiple aggregate functions with subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, count, pivot

Noob question, but I was hoping someone could help walk me through the logic of my problem.
So I have SELECT with 3 columns. I want to count the rows with two different values in column1 and then a calculate the median grouped by column2.
Then I want to the same for a different value in column1.

How would I do this? I have this so far but I don't know where to put the median functions?

```
SELECT region, product, year
 (SELECT COUNT (*),
  FROM mytable
  WHERE product = dairy and product = meat) as count_dairy_meat
 (SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM mytable
  WHERE product = veg) as count_veg

FROM mytable

GROUP BY region, product, year;
```

I would like the results to look like this

```
         count_dairy_meat   count_veg   Median
Region1             
Region2             
Region3             
Total
```

Comment: Please provide sample daa and desired results, as tabular text. It is hard to assess what you want from your explanation and query.

Comment: How can column1 be both x and y? Did you mean OR?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I made an edit and hopefully that helps what I'm trying to ask

Comment: Maybe you could include some sample rows from mytable and then show what the results should be assuming those rows were all that was in mytable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *suspect* that you are looking for conditional aggregation. The logic is to generate separate count for "meal" and "veg" `product` is:

```
select
    region,
    product,
    year,
    sum(case when product = 'meal' then 1 else 0 end) count_meat,
    sum(case when product = 'veg'  then 1 else O end) count_veg
from mytable
group by region, product, year
```

I don't get which median you want to compute. Oracle has a `median()` aggregate function that you would probably use.

Comment: Thanks! I do want something like that. Can I add a 'and' statement to the sum to have meat and dairy for the first sum? I'm confused by the median myself. I'm told to get the median per group (meat and dairy as one and veg as the other) per region.

Comment: @Petra: you mean meat *or* dairy, so: `sum(case when product in ('meat', 'dairy') then 1 else 0 end) count_meat_or_dairy`